# error while install ernw/ss7MAPer

Tags: erlang

I am trying to install ernw_ss7MAPer package. In the readme file it has some tutorial, but in last command (for building it: `sudo ./rebar co`) I have the following problem:

```
==> pkt (compile)
==> epcap (compile)
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:34: can't find include file "pkt.hrl"
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:94: record ether undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:95: record ipv4 undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:99: record ether undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:100: record ipv4 undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:103: record ipv4 undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:159: record tcp undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:161: variable 'Seqno' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:162: variable 'Ackno' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:163: variable 'Win' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:164: record udp undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:165: variable 'Ulen' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:166: record icmp undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:167: variable 'Type' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:168: variable 'Code' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:172: variable 'SPort' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:172: record tcp undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:173: variable 'SPort' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:173: record udp undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:174: variable 'DPort' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:174: record tcp undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:175: variable 'DPort' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:175: record udp undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:189: record tcp undefined
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:192: variable 'ACK' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:192: variable 'CWR' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:192: variable 'ECE' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:192: variable 'FIN' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:192: variable 'PSH' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:192: variable 'RST' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:192: variable 'SYN' is unbound
/home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl:192: variable 'URG' is unbound
Compiling /home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap/src/sniff.erl failed:
ERROR: compile failed while processing /home/user/Desktop/ss7mapper/deps/epcap: rebar_abort
```

How can I fix this issue?
I also should say that `pkt.hrl`'s location is `ss7mapper/deps/pkt/include/pkt.hrl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just copy the pkt.hrl from this path

> ss7MAPer/deps/pkt/include

to

> ss7MAPer/deps/epcap/include